# Static site on S3 with Github OAuth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, oauth

Title says it all: is it possible to host a static-generated site on S3 and restrict access to it based on Github OAuth?

Scenario: You generate a static site (using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) or whatever) and you [upload it to S3 as a static site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html). Is there some combination of AWS services (API Gateway, Lambda, etc.) that can make it so that only members of my Github organization can access this site? Authenticating with [Github's OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)? Anyone not authenticated should be treated with a 404.

Has anyone done this or know how to do it? Is such a thing possible [***without*** running a backing server (EC2, Heroku, DigitalOcean Droplet, etc.) of some kind](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-auth#the-problem)?

Looking for a complete answer that outlines steps on how to set this up (if possible) with the lowest cost/complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. I've followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway) in the past to secure a static site on S3 behind an Auth0 authentication, using DynamoDB as the user account store, and API Gateway + AWS Lambda as the authentication service. That was an AngularJS SPA, but the general concept should be the same.

Github is listed as an [Auth0 identity provider](https://auth0.com/docs/identityproviders). I would recommend looking at [this documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) for using Auth0 on your site. Once you get it working you would have to configure your static site generator to include the authentication JavaScript code on every page it generates.